# Best fit formula to estimate the task execution duration

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to figure out a best estimation calculation for my newly creating tasks running parallel on the same time..
As a first step of my calculation my formula will be Duration(D) = Count(c)/networkthroughput(T). So for the given starting time I can find the duration for 1 task easily and for the next task with the same time, Am doing some calculation myself and I am expecting some idea or relevant formula for the same for the attached image.
[image]

And here i need to calculate the duration for each task separately..Idea's / Solutions are welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: You've put effort into the question with the picture, so that's a big plus, but the question is too broad; you're asking to code the whole thing?? Better to write code and if you're stuck on line X then ask a question about line X.

Comment: thanks  frenchie :) I am still deriving the formula with some sample values and at some point getting negative against the formula..so I just tried to know if anybody having a simple mathematical formula for this...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a function that you pass in your function to time as an argument, then wrap the function call in a couple of date variables?

```
//Assuming functionToTime is marked async Task
public async Task<TimeSpan>(Action functionToTime){
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    await functionToTime;
    return (DateTime.Now - startTime);
}
```

If `functionToTime` in not `async`, you would want to call the function by:

```
await Task.Run(() => functionToTime);
```

You can change it to meet your needs, but I think this should be a good starting point.